# Best way to calculate powers of 2 in Java

Tags: math, bit-shift

Given an integer n, find 2^n. Here are two methods I know:

**Method 1**

`int a = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    a = a << 1;`

**Method 2**

```
int a = Math.pow(2,n);
```

Given how fast bitshifts are, I was wondering which method would be faster. Also, how does Math.pow() work and why do people generally say it is slow?

Comment: If you dig into the source code for `Math.pow()`, you will that ultimately see a `native` method for exponentiation is being called.  Most likely, this would end up using bit shift operators under the hood, on whatever OS is actually running the Java code.

Comment: As for which method would be faster, you can test that on your own. Regarding how `Math.pow()` works, you can dig into its source code as @TimBiegeleisen said